# How to make offline Funnel graph in iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

How can I achieve [this](https://plus.google.com/photos/105918944612452393134/albums/5881557743791382673/5883680170118309330?banner=pwa&pid=5883680170118309330&oid=105918944612452393134) funnel type graph in iPad.
I want to make it offline.

Any idea or logic or code is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Funnel Type Chart means Funnel = Shape(Grapics) + Chart (Logic)

Funnel charts are a type of chart, often used to represent stages in a sales process and show the amount of potential revenue for each stage

For Stages and the amount of potential revenue ( Save the values in a container) and arrange them in a greater to smaller logic.

Now for Funnel shape we should use Bézier Path Basics (UIBezierPath)

bcoz UIBezierpath object may contain on or more subpaths that deifne the overall path( we have to provide this according to our (stages and potential revenue values).

This Bézier Path is really helpfull for making Funnel type Chart Offline.

For Bézier Path Basics follow this link:-
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.I went through the link given by you but as i am new to ios development unable to understand how to create funnel using Bézier Path.So can you please give some line of codes as i need it badly......